# Two-Dimensional Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I had a question in my assignment where i used the following way to define a 2D array:

```
// Allocating two two-dimensional matrix
int** matrix1 = new int*[rows];
for( int i=0; i!=rows; ++i )
matrix1[i] = new int[cols];
int** matrix2 = new int*[rows];
for( int i=0; i!=rows; ++i )
matrix2[i] = new int[cols];
```

I found it really hard to understand this method and even after completing the course, i find this too confusing. I managed during the semester by finding a simpler way on the internet but i would really love to know exactly what is happening here.

Can someone please explain it in as simple words as possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this image explains rather good how it's put together. `array` being one of your matrix.

[image]

`matrix1` points to an array of pointers (rows), where each pointer points to an array of ints (columns).

Answer (score 1):

dynamic 2D array is basically an array of pointers, syntax wise, it is:

```
int** matrix1; //for integer 2D array
```

`matrix1` is an `array of pointers` that points to int. int arrays are decayed to `int*`. Therefore, you have the above syntax. To better understand it, think about how you deal with dynamic 1D arrays as follows:

```
int* A = new int[SIZE_OF_ARRAY];
```

here, `A` is of type `int*`, it is functionally similar to static array `A[SIZE_OF_ARRAY]` if `SIZE_OF_ARRAY` is a compile time constant. Now assuming you have another static array `B[ROWS][COLS]`, with `ROWS` and `COLS` compile time constants, however, if these array size values are not constants at compile time, you need to allocate memory dynamically, so for `B`, you have to do the same thing as you did for `matrix1`:

```
int **B;
```

To allocate memory, you have to first allocate `how many pointers the array of pointers store`, meanwhile, you also need to allocate memory `for how many int elements each pointer points to`, so you need the nested for loops for this purpose.

In C++, it is better to use `vector<vector<int>>` to replace `int** matrix1`.

You may view a memory layout of 2D arrays here: http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/23two-dim-array-memory-layout.html